# Samba: system group mapping

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, group

I have w2008R2 PDC and Linux server with samba and winbind. Now I'd like to add some domain users to Unix `adm` group in AD.

Let's say I have `adm` group defined in AD, and every user from this group will be a member of Unix `adm` group when logging to Linux over PuTTY.

I expected that it will be possible with `net groupmap`, so I tried:

```
net groupmap add ntgroup="adm"  unixgroup=adm   type=l
```

but it is not working. If I login I see that I'm a member of `adm` group, but I don't have `adm` group permissions (i.e I can't view syslog).

I've tried also

```
net groupmap add ntgroup="adm"  unixgroup=adm   type=d
```

but the behavior is the same.